# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -40

Tags: java, rabbitmq, avro

I get this strange error while de-serializing the binary data:
The following is my implementation of the reader:

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/main/avro/queue_data.avsc"));

SpecificDatumReader<QueueData> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<QueueData>(schema);

Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(body, null);

QueueData queueData = reader.read(null, decoder);
```

schema: https://pastebin.com/GUJgzeh4
Sample Data: https://pastebin.com/CUf1U3iL

when I run it throws the exception as below:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -40
at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:424)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
at com.bpawan.messaging.Sender.readFromQueue(Sender.java:57)
at com.bpawan.messaging.Sender.access$000(Sender.java:15)
at com.bpawan.messaging.Sender$1.handleDelivery(Sender.java:38)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It's very sad that the error message does not tells anything what the problem actually is. Tried debugging few times but no success.

The producer of the data is written in php.

Comment: did you get any solution for this, i'm also facing similar error while reading avro message from Spark sql function from_avro?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably occurring because your body contains a layout that doesn't fit with the schema. There are 41 bytes in your body that don't match with fields in schema, it may be a trailer or header or anything else, you need to understand how your body bytes are being created and adapt the schema or remove the exceeding bytes.